# Escaping placeholder characters in WPF date formatting

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, formatting

I'm trying to display a date in a WPF TextBlock in the following format:

```
09:35 Uhr
```

My first try of course didn't work:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime,StringFormat={}{0:hh:mm Uhr}}"
```

resulted in the string `09:35 U9r` since the `h` in the string after the date is interpreted as aplaceholder for the hour. Writing the `h` as `&#104;` also does not work, neither does trying to escape it as `{{h}}`.

So, it it actually possible to achieve what I want to do? Or would I have to break up the string into two `TextBlock`s, use a custom converter or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use \ according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719856(v=vs.71).aspx

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTime,StringFormat={}{0:hh:mm U\\hr}}"
```

Alternatively you can also use a IValueConverter something like

```
public class MyFormatter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type tagetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
     return string.Format("{0:hh:mm}", value)+" Uhr";
  }
...
//Just throw NotImplemented for ConvertBack
}
```

Comment: For me, `\\` does not work. Should be so: StringFormat={}{0:hh:mm U\\hr}.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StartTime, StringFormat={}{0:hh:mm} Uhr}" ... />
```

Comment: This works, too. I accepted the other answer since it seems more complete and links to the documentation (where I missed the solution...).